# SQL Query for retrieving records separated by seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a Microsoft SQL Server query for retrieving the oldest record in which the text fields are the same, but the dates are 30 seconds or less apart. Here is an example:

My table:

```
RecordID     TextField1              TextField2           DateField1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            SomeData1               SomeData2            9/11/2011 2:33:00pm
2            SomeData3               SomeData4            9/11/2011 2:33:15pm
3            SomeData3               SomeData4            9/11/2011 2:33:18pm
4            SomeData3               SomeData4            9/11/2011 2:42:12pm
5            SomeData1               SomeData2            9/11/2011 2:33:01pm
6            SomeData6               SomeData7            9/11/2011 2:33:01pm
7            SomeData1               SomeData2            9/12/2011 2:33:00pm
8            SomeData6               SomeData8            9/11/2011 2:33:03pm
```

Okay, so in this example, I want a query that will pull the rows in which `TextField1=TextField1` and `TextField2=TextField2` and the dates between them are 30 seconds or less (I want the oldest of the two returned). So the query, in this example, should return:

```
RecordID     TextField1              TextField2           DateField1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            SomeData1               SomeData2            9/11/2011 2:33:00pm
2            SomeData3               SomeData4            9/11/2011 2:33:15pm
```

RecordID 8 is not returned because TextField2 is different.

Hopefully I explained this clearly enough. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Nothing really because I'm not sure how to go about comparing records to future records in a dataset. In other words, I have `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE TextField1=??? AND TextField2=???` I am stumped on how to compare against records in the aggregate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't understand everything on your question.

This is a generic SQL query that will compare the records of you table, against the same table, looking for records with different RecordID, but equal TextField1 and TextField2.

Leave a comment if this looks like what you want and we can improve this query to get exactly what you are looking for.

UPDATED:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table AS t1
INNER JOIN my_table AS t2
ON (
    t1.RecordID < t2.recordID
    AND
    DATEDIFF(second, t1.DateField1, t2.DateField1) <= 30
    AND
    t1.TextField1 = t2.TextField1
    AND
    t2.TextField2 = t1.TextField2
);
```

Comment: Yes this seems like what I need. Except I just want records in which t1.DateField and t2.DateField are 30 seconds or less apart.

Comment: What about the updated query?? I've changed the comparison of the RecordID, to avoid "duplicated" results (RecordID 1 & 2, and 2 & 1).

Comment: Would using `DATEADD` be more efficient than `DATEDIFF`? `t1.DateField1 <= DATEADD(second, 30, t1.DateField1)`

Answer (score 1):

This returns the two records you are looking for in your example.  The join between `t1` and `t2` returns the records that meet your criteria, and then joining to `t3` returns the oldest of the rows meeting the criteria.

```
;
with TestCTE(RecordID, TextField1, TextField2, DateField1)
as
(
    select 1, 'SomeData1', 'SomeData2', cast('9/11/2011 2:33:00pm' as datetime)
    union
    select 2, 'SomeData3', 'SomeData4', cast('9/11/2011 2:33:15pm' as datetime)
    union
    select 3, 'SomeData3', 'SomeData4', cast('9/11/2011 2:33:18pm' as datetime)
    union 
    select 4, 'SomeData3', 'SomeData4', cast('9/11/2011 2:42:12pm' as datetime)
    union 
    select 5, 'SomeData1', 'SomeData2', cast('9/11/2011 2:33:01pm' as datetime)
    union
    select 6, 'SomeData6', 'SomeData7', cast('9/11/2011 2:33:01pm' as datetime)
    union
    select 7, 'SomeData1', 'SomeData2', cast('9/12/2011 2:33:00pm' as datetime)
    union
    select 8, 'SomeData6', 'SomeData8', cast('9/11/2011 2:33:03pm' as datetime)
)
select t1.*
from TestCTE t1
    join TestCTE t2 on t1.RecordID <> t2.RecordID 
                        and t1.TextField1 = t2.TextField1 
                        and t1.TextField2 = t2.TextField2 
                        and datediff(second, t1.DateField1, t2.DateField1) <= 30
    join
    (
        select TextField1, TextField2, min(DateField1) as MinDate
        from TestCTE
        group by TextField1, TextField2
    ) t3 on t1.TextField1 = t3.TextField1 
            and t1.TextField2 = t3.TextField2 
            and t1.DateField1 = t3.MinDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a simple self-join and not trying to make it more than it should.  By doing the self-join and applying the group by, the following should get it done for you.

The self-join is on both text fields, and the first table's Record ID always GREATER than the one in the second table....  Then, the comparison on the date/time factor of 30 seconds.

Due to a comment from ADrift, and re-looking at the data, what I THOUGHT was a date/time stamp field on the record would always be increasing is not always the case...  Slight change... Get the latest date/time for the given text1 and text2, then re-join back for rest of the details.

```
select
      YT3.*
   from
      ( select
              YT.TextField1,
              YT.TextField2,
              MIN( YT.DateField1) OldestDateTime,
           from
              YourTable YT
                 Join YourTable YT2
                    on YT.TextField1 = YT2.TextField1
                   AND YT.TextField2 = YT2.TextField2
                   AND YT.RecordID > YT2.RecordID
                   AND datediff(second, YT.DateField1, YT2.DateField1) <= 30
           group by
              YT.TextField1,
              YT.TextFIeld2 ) PreQuery

         JOIN YourTable YT3
            on PreQuery.TextField1 = YT3.TextField1
           AND PreQuery.TextField2 = YT3.TextField2
           AND PreQuery.OldestDateTime = YT3.DateField1
   order by
      whatever...
```

Comment: My understanding is that he wants the entire row, not the `max` of RecordID and `max` of DateField1, which may come from different rows.

Comment: @adrift, Thanks for the feedback on that.  I was under the impression the date/time would always increase, and also missed that wanted the OLDEST record... so I changed to using MIN(), not max() and did the final join to get all the details associated with the OLDEST record.

Comment: @icemanind, adjusted per comment by adrift, I think this revised query gets what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there can only be no more than two adjacent rows (those within 30 second from each other) and you are on SQL Server 2005 or later version:

```
WITH sampledata (RecordID, TextField1, TextField2, DateField1) AS
(
  SELECT 1, 'SomeData1', 'SomeData2', CAST('20110911 14:33:00' AS datetime) UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'SomeData3', 'SomeData4', CAST('20110911 14:33:15' AS datetime) UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'SomeData3', 'SomeData4', CAST('20110911 14:33:18' AS datetime) UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'SomeData3', 'SomeData4', CAST('20110911 14:42:12' AS datetime) UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'SomeData1', 'SomeData2', CAST('20110911 14:33:01' AS datetime) UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'SomeData6', 'SomeData7', CAST('20110911 14:33:01' AS datetime) UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'SomeData1', 'SomeData2', CAST('20110912 14:33:00' AS datetime) UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'SomeData6', 'SomeData8', CAST('20110911 14:33:03' AS datetime)
),
ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TextField1, TextField2 ORDER BY DateField1)
  FROM sampledata
),
SELECT
  r1.RecordID,
  r1.TextField1,
  r1.TextField2,
  r1.DateField1
FROM ranked r1
  INNER JOIN ranked r2 ON r1.TextField1 = r2.TextField1
                      AND r1.TextField2 = r2.TextField2
                      AND r1.rn = r2.rn - 1
WHERE r2.DateField1 BETWEEN r1.DateField1 AND DATEADD(SECOND, 30, r1.DateField1)
```

Output:

```
RecordID    TextField1 TextField2 DateField1
----------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------
1           SomeData1  SomeData2  2011-09-11 14:33:00.000
2           SomeData3  SomeData4  2011-09-11 14:33:15.000
```